# How to use m2ecipse and maven in Idea IDE correctly?

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

Currently, I found that it's very inefficient use of Maven in our team. So I have this question.

We have a large project consists of 300-500 modules which are organized by Maven 3, I have divided it into 10 sub-projects, so each sub-project have a root `pom.xml`. Say they are project1, project2, .. projectN. I mainly work on `project3` consists of 30 modules, they are then depended by `project4` and `project5`.

```
project3:
    module3-1  SNAPSHOT
    module3-2  SNAPSHOT
    module3-3  SNAPSHOT
    module3-4  SNAPSHOT
    module3-5  SNAPSHOT
    module3-6  RELEASE
    ...
    module3-30 RELEASE
```

In project3, some not so often changes modules are released, and some (module3-1..3-5) are changed very frequently, so I use SNAPSHOT versions here.

We have run an Archiva server to manage all the artifacts, include both released and snapshots version.

Now the problem is, when I changed something in my `project3`, generally I would like to deploy the whole sub-project:

```
[my-ubuntu] ~/project3/$ mvn clean; mvn deploy
...
EVERYTHING SUCCEED
[my-ubuntu] ~/project3/$
```

For what I expect is, all the snapshot versions should be automatically downloaded & updated in other people's machines.

In command line, it's worked as expected:

```
[john's ubuntu] ~/project4/$ mvn package
...
download http://archiva-server/snapshots/project3/...-SNAPSHOT... [SUCCEEDED]
...
EVERYTHING SUCCEED
[john's ubuntu] ~/project4/$
```

However, Gin hate command line, so he use M2eclipse, but M2eclipse won't automaticlly update the snapshots. I have tried:

```
TRY 1: 
    Disable dependency resolution
    Enable dependency resolution
    (This take maybe 30 minutes, and make eclipse hang, so I don't like. And it seems not work most of time, not download the latest snapshots sometimes)

TRY 2:
    Update all dependnecies
    Refresh projects
    (This take about maybe 5 minutes, but not work some time, not download the latest snapshots sometimes)

TRY 3:
    Delete all projects from eclipse workspace
    Re-import all projects
    (This take maybe 10 minutes, and most "clean" way, though not very fast but okay)
    (But not download the latest snapshots sometimes)

TRY 4:
    [gin's ubuntu] ~/project4/$ cd ~/.m2/repository/../project3
    [gin's ubuntu] ~/.m2/repository/../project3 $ find -name 'resolve-*' -delete
    Refresh eclipse projects
    (This take about maybe 5 minutes? Well I haven't time it, though.)
    (This is the best resolution in my experience, it downloads all snapshots everytime, so it's the final-resolution, well sounds like problem-killer.)
```

So, I my personal experience, to delete `resolve-*` files in local repository seems the best resolution, but it's just not feel good.

Compared with command-line invoke `mvn`, all IDE sucks.. Well maybe I didn't manage Maven in a correct way?

I'd like to know the best workflows to use Maven correctly in Eclipse/Idea stuff IDEs.

Comment: Is your project in the end a single application or may be parts of an application?

Comment: m2eclipse is a plugin for Eclipse and of course not for IntelliJ...IntelliJ has support for Maven without m2eclipse.

Comment: Well I mean both `m2eclipse` and `Maven in Idea`, because both Eclipse and Idea are used in the team. At the end, there are libraries and applications and webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should think about the organization of your projects and their relationship to each other. May be you should about Multimodule builds to handle some of the situations in a better way.

Furthmore you have to change the configuration of the repositories to download the SNAPSHOT versions directly. Change the settings.xml in particular the [update policy.](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)

Comment: The point is: everything go well in command line build, but is not so expected in IDEs. So, I'd like to know what's your practice of co-develop with snapshot modules, how do you update snapshots in m2eclipse, and how do you update snapshots in Idea? Do you `Update all dependencies` when you have received a `Project3 is modified, so update your maven dependencies` mail?

Comment: No..check the configuration and if you need directly get the updated just configure it that way. The default is to get the new snapshot version after a day.

Comment: Oh, where can I config the timeout, then?

Comment: excerpt from the doc: updatePolicy: This element specifies how often updates should attempt to occur. Maven will compare the local POM's timestamp (stored in a repository's maven-metadata file) to the remote. The choices are: always, daily (default), interval:X (where X is an integer in minutes) or never.